# Why isn't ng-container responding to styling?

Tags: css, angular

I want to style ng-container like add borders when on hover or show a button inside this tags on hover but this isn't possible. ng-container doesn't seem to be responsive to styling. Is rendered on DOM and if not what can I use to access it?

Answer (score 9):

According to Angular official [docs](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue) `<ng-container>` is a grouping element that doesn't interfere with styles or layout because Angular doesn't put it in the DOM. It's only meant to be used as a container for structural directives when you need some HTML elements immediate children to be of a specific type. For styling you would have to go with regular elements instead.