# Unable to use ngClass with ng-container to build table, Angular

Tags: angular, ng-class, ng-container

I have a generic table component and I want to make the row hoverable by binding class using *ngClass* to a *ng-container*. However I an error.

The code:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let row of manager.rows" [ngClass]="manager.config.onRowSelect ? 'row-selectable' : ''">
                    <ng-container *ngFor="let cell of row.displayData">
                        <div (click)="row.onClick(row.item)" class="cell-divider">
                            <!-- Image -->
                            <div *ngIf="cell.isImage" class="cell" style="display: flex; align-items: center; padding: 3px;">
                                <img [src]="cell.data">
                            </div>
                            <!-- Data -->
                            <div *ngIf="!cell.isImage" class="cell">
                                {{cell.data}}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </ng-container>
                    <!-- Column Actions -->
                    <div *ngIf="manager.config.rowActions && manager.config.rowActions.length > 0" style="display: flex; gap: 2px; align-items: center;" class="cell-divider">
                        <div *ngFor="let action of row.actions" >
                            <ng-container>
                                <app-ui-icon-button (clicked)="action.action(row.item)" [iconSize]="20" [tooltip]="action.tooltip" [backgroundTransparent]="true" [iconColor]="action.color" [icon]="action.icon"></app-ui-icon-button>
                            </ng-container>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</ng-container>
```

The error I get:

[image]

If I remove the ngClass part from the 1st ng-container then I don't get the error.

**Solutions that won't work:**

- Replace the ng-container with a div, because above the ng-container
  is a table layout and it will ruin the layout.
- Add a div between the 1st ng-container and the 1st div, because this
  will also ruin the layout.

Why can't I bind ngClass to ngContainer and how would I solve my issue?

Comment: you can't apply `ngClass` to `ng-container` see this SO post for more information https://stackoverflow.com/a/61299689/5621827  Create a stackblitz of your problem so you can ask for alternative solutions

Comment: I googled and used ChatGPT and no where they said I can't use it together. Very weird. Thank you @jitender. If you make an answer I can mark your answer as the preferred answer.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this method, create template**

```
  <ng-template #customTemplate>
      <div class="class-name">
        Bla Bla Bla!
      </div>
   </ng-template>
```

**And call it within container**

```
  <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="customTemplate"></ng-container>
```